# How should I pass a mutable double array from Python to a dll library using ctypes and not getting access violations?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to call the functions in a dll lib with python. (To be specific, I have a IBIS-AMI dll library at hand and I'm trying to call the AMI_init() funciton, which takes in an impulse response and modify it in place according to some parameters).

I read in a c_double array of impulse response and give it to the function AMI_Init(), expecting its contents to be modified by the function, but instead it gave me an error with "OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00007FF8220C418D".
My code is as follows:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import csv

dll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\Users\zhoutj\PycharmProjects\pythonProject_ami_test\Trimode16_AMI_Tx64.dll")

print(dll.AMI_Init)
dll.AMI_Init.restype = c_long
dll.AMI_Init.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), c_long, c_long, c_double, c_double, POINTER(c_char)]

with open('tx_impulse_eq.csv','rt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    #rows = [row for row in reader]
   # for row in reader:
        #print(row)
    column = [row[1] for row in reader]
    impulse_response = column[20:]
    #print( column)

print(impulse_response)

Impulse_Response = (c_double*1024)()
for i in range(1024):
    Impulse_Response[i] = c_double(float(impulse_response[i]))
  
print(Impulse_Response)

row_size = c_long(1024)
aggressors = c_long(0)
sample_interval = c_double(2.5E-11)
bit_time = c_double(2E-10)
parameter_in =  '(Trimode16_Tx   (Model_Specific(tx_back_channel_calculation  0)(tx_vpp  1.00)(c1 -15)(c2 64 )(c3 -15))) '
parameter_in_c = c_char_p(id(parameter_in))
print(parameter_in_c)

dll.AMI_Init(Impulse_Response, row_size, aggressors, sample_interval, bit_time, parameter_in_c)
```

I think this happens because the function is trying to write into an inmutable memory. ImpulseResponse is an input to the function and the function tries to modify it in place.

I searched the internet and some tutorials suggested using create_string_buffer to copy my array into a buffer before giving that buffer to the function. But there's only create_string_buffer and no buffer for double arrays.

Comment: `parameter_in =  b'(Trimode16_Tx   (Model_Specific(tx_back_channel_calculation  0)(tx_vpp  1.00)(c1 -15)(c2 64 )(c3 -15))) '` and `parameter_in_c = c_char_p(parameter_in)`?

Answer (score 0):

The following is incorrect.  The parameter should be a byte string (`bytes` type) instead of a Unicode string (`str` type).  The later corresponds to a C `wchar_t*` while the former is correct for C `char*`.  The `id()` of that parameter is the address of the `PyObject*` representing that object, and not the address of the actual content.  Just use the byte string for the parameter and `ctypes` will pass it correctly.

```
parameter_in =  '(Trimode16_Tx   (Model_Specific(tx_back_channel_calculation  0)(tx_vpp  1.00)(c1 -15)(c2 64 )(c3 -15))) '
parameter_in_c = c_char_p(id(parameter_in))
```

Corrected:

```
parameter_in =  b'(Trimode16_Tx   (Model_Specific(tx_back_channel_calculation  0)(tx_vpp  1.00)(c1 -15)(c2 64 )(c3 -15))) '
```

There is no need to wrap the additional parameters in `ctypes` types as well.  `ctypes` knows the type to use via `.argtypes`.

Below is a test DLL using the implied types from `.argtypes/.restype` since the C prototype wasn't supplied, followed by the Python code to call it.

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
long AMI_Init(double* impulse_response, long row_size, long aggressors,
              double sample_interval, double bit_time, const char* parameter_in) {
    // Show that the parameters were passed correctly.
    printf("%ld %ld %lg %lg\n%s\n",
        row_size, aggressors, sample_interval, bit_time, parameter_in);
    for(int i = 0; i < row_size; ++i)
        impulse_response[i] *= 512;  // Modify the buffer for demo.
    return 1;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

# Here I've used CDLL.  It's correct for __cdecl calling convention on Win32.
# WinDLL is for __stdcall calling convention on Win32.  On Win64 either will work
# as there is only one calling convention, but for portability use the correct one
# for a Win32 build.
dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.AMI_Init.restype = ct.c_long
dll.AMI_Init.argtypes = ct.POINTER(ct.c_double), ct.c_long, ct.c_long, ct.c_double, ct.c_double, ct.c_char_p

# This was already a writable buffer.
# Here I've just initialized the 1024-element array with 1/1024 - 1023/1024
# using a list comprehension and * for parameter expansion of the initializers.
impulse_response = (ct.c_double * 1024)(*[n/1024 for n in range(1024)])
row_size = 1024
aggressors = 0
sample_interval = 2.5e-11
bit_time = 2e-10

# Use a byte string (leading b'') for a C char*
parameter_in =  b'(Trimode16_Tx   (Model_Specific(tx_back_channel_calculation  0)(tx_vpp  1.00)(c1 -15)(c2 64 )(c3 -15))) '

dll.AMI_Init(impulse_response, row_size, aggressors, sample_interval, bit_time, parameter_in)

# Display the first and last few modified values
# which should be 0, .5, ... 511.0, 511.5.
print(impulse_response[:5], impulse_response[-5:])
```

Output:

```
1024 0 2.5e-11 2e-10
(Trimode16_Tx   (Model_Specific(tx_back_channel_calculation  0)(tx_vpp  1.00)(c1 -15)(c2 64 )(c3 -15)))
[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0] [509.5, 510.0, 510.5, 511.0, 511.5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think I understand how to pass a double * to c lib. How about passing double ** and char ** ? For example, if the function demands char** instead of char*, do I use addressof(parameter_in) or ctypes.byref(parameter_in)? I'm not very familiar with these data types and google suggests me to do so.